# Reactjs make infinity carousel

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I'm new in React. I need to make infinity carousel without backing scroll when all elements from list run out. For example we got list [1,2,3,4] and now is element 4 and click to button to right i must to add new element (1) after element 4, than 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3,... And similar into left. But I don't want to install another library and packages.
Something like that. Thank you

[image]

Comment: I know you said you didn't want to use another library, but take a look at https://swiperjs.com/ . They have a React component that I've used. If you don't use them, it may still give you some ideas.

Comment: You're likely going to have to clone elements. Take a look [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-react-cloneelement-function/). Never done it myself, so can't help you further. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, do you ever need to have 2 of the same elements on the page visible at the same time, like 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 (that's what I was assuming)? Or will there be at most 1 of each item on the page? If you only need the item to appear at max once, let me know and I can help out.

Comment: @Nathan I need to be on page max 3 element (previus, now, and next) - for example I got list of 100 items and I dont need to have all of them at page - I need only max 3 element.

Comment: I don't want for now using another library - I just study and want to understand how to do something like this

Comment: I read some article and than was say to use in similar situation virtual scroll

Comment: Maybe this'll help: https://dev.to/adamklein/build-your-own-virtual-scroll-part-i-11ib

Comment: Do you actually needing scrolling, or can you just support arrow keys + clicking "next" and "previous" icons? Infinite scrolling would be much harder than just creating the effect of a carousal by sliding the last element of the list (looping around when you hit zero) from the left. It would only exist when you start navigating to it, just give it a -x transform to start and transition it to 0 transform.

Comment: Better will If will something) I don't have anything now, so any is better than nothing. So If you have some idea I will accept all

Comment: Yes smithing like into this article upper, I want to do similar by horizontal and infinity